# Flexbox layout - element width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I achieve with flexbox this?

[image]

> .img should have 25% of width .info should have 75% of width .row
>   should have always 100% .half should have 50%

Here is my code  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrBRgP

```
.wrap {display: flex;}
.row { width: 100%;}
.half {width: 50%;}
```

Why the row have not 100% of the div?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) instead of `width`.

You also need to apply flex layout to the rows.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great guide to flex.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div {
  border: 1px black dotted;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
.info {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}
.half {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lvrfnaXz651qibz0jo1_r1_500.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Hello How Are You</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="half">1</div>
    <div class="half">2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half">1</div>
    <div class="half">2</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

#### Update from Comment by @ZcelaAnonymní

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div {
  border: 1px black dotted;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.info {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
}
.half {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lvrfnaXz651qibz0jo1_r1_500.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Hello How Are You</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="half">1</div>
    <div class="half">2</div>
    <div class="half">1</div>
    <div class="half">2</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but row should have div 1 and 2. Next row should have also 1 and 2.

Comment: @KarolinaTicha Updated

Comment: Is it posible to force .half to fill 50% of element so 2. .half will be on one row and 4 .half will be at two rows etc?